# Find all files matching a given pattern AND excluding a given pattern?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find, systems-programming

I want to find all files in a directory that match a given pattern say A and don't match a given pattern say B

What I've tried:
Doing "ls -I B" gives me all files which match the pattern B. But I'm not getting any leads on how to do what I want to.

Comment: How does `ls -l B` give you all the files that don't match the pattern  `B`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `find . -name "pattern"` and then add a negative condition for the pattern you don't want to have:

```
find . -name "pattern_A" ! -name "pattern_B"
```

#### Example

Let's look for those files whose name contains a `A` but not a `B`:

```
$ ls -1
adfadAadsa
adfBasdA
Aksjdflksj
asdfBasdf
Badsf

$ find . -name "*A*" ! -name "*B*"
./Aksjdflksj
./adfadAadsa
```

Comment: +1 `-regex` option of `find` is often useful to allow for complex patterns.

Comment: You can add depth control. To not search subdirectories: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "pattern_A" ! -name "pattern_B"`